# How can I change the options that `iframe-resizer` is using?

Tags: iframe, iframe-resizer

I have an iframe on my page and I'm using [iframe-resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer) to have it resize to match its content. I'm using the `maxHeight` option to limit its size. This is working fine.

However, sometimes I want to change the value of `maxHeight`, in response to actions in the parent page.

I've tried calling `iframeResizer(newOptions, myIframe)` but this doesn't seem to change anything - the old options are still in effect.

Is there a way I can change the options on the fly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options you pass to iframe-resizer are not changeable after it has been setup.

Comment: Thanks. In the end I had to remove the iframe, re-add it, then re-initialize iframeResizer.